# Compiling QEMU in ubuntu 20.04 by command `make -j` makes system hang

Tags: 20.04, compiling, virtualization, gcc, qemu

I want to build qemu from source in my Ubuntu 20.04. It seems ordinary to build QEMU by following the official instruction.

Execution of  command `make -j` works well at the beginning, and slows down gradually after a period of compiling. Finally, the entire system hangs, keyboard and mouse freeze. The only way to recover from such a situation is pressing power button.

So, it that a compatibility problem of mismatch of gcc and the source code? Or is that I use `-j` option illegally?

Update:

1. Removal of `-j` option makes the problem gone.
2. Using parallel jobs less than the number of CPU cores by appending `-jN` option also eliminates the problem. Single `-j` option without an argument makes `make` command utilize the whole cores to do compiling.

Comment: Not very much info  so I can only guess that you have no swap, and are running out of RAM. Read `man mkswap swapon`

Comment: @waltinator I am not very agree with you. I continuously inspect memory usage by `watch -n 1 free -h`, and before system halt, free reports that it is still unused memory available. Also, I have swap partition enabled as default.

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify "`-j`" without a specific number, try to use "`-j4`".

> -j [jobs], --jobs[=jobs]
> Specifies  the  number  of  jobs (commands) to run simultaneously.  If there is more than one -j option, the last one is effective.  If the -j option is given without an argument, make will not limit the number of jobs that can run simultaneously. When make invokes a sub-make, all instances of make will coordinate to run the specified number of jobs at a time; see the section PARALLEL
> MAKE AND THE JOBSERVER for details.